# cheating in theoretical exams as there is no time!

Tags: exams, cheating

We all know cheating in exams is almost an academic crime. However, a friend of mine has some extraordinary circumstances..
He works full time job and studies at uni at the same time five days a week so he has no time to study.

He can't quit the job as he is paying for uni and he can't stop his studies as he needs a IT Bachelor degree for his job (He is actually working some administrative stuff for the meantime).

He is very hardworking and clever guy. He does all his assignments very perfectly.It is only that he doesn’t find time to memorize stuff for exams i.e. he studies for the important content exams such as coding but he doesn't for the theoretical parts such as: "define system administration" or "explain validation in JS", and this sort of thing, using [cheat sheets](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5a/Cheating.JPG).

He deserves full marks for his hardworking and attention. That's why he cheats the theoretical parts in exams. He gets full marks and -until now at least- survives in every exam he cheats although many of his colleagues get caught.

He is feeling guilty. He doesn't want to lose marks over theoretical content he can't find time to study, and at the same time, he doesn't feel proud nor happy with all his 'A' grades he is getting- the curriculum is full of theoretical contents.

He thought about confessing to his professors but what is the benefit of that!

He asked me, and I am asking you in turn, for any suggestions he can/should do.

Comment: How exactly does he "cheat in the theoretical parts"?

Comment: copying from some cheat sheets. something like [THIS](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5a/Cheating.JPG)

Comment: What should he do?  Stop cheating, get his butt in gear, and study.  And he doesn't "deserve" anything he hasn't earned.

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of answer you expect. If he feels bad, he can stop cheating for the future. For the past, he wouldn't gain anything by confessing anything to anyone, the best way to remedy that is to learn the missed material, i.e. the material he cheated on, to catch up on the knowledge required for his degree.

Comment: Working full time is no excuse for cheating. Many people have done it for both undergraduate and graduate studies. There is no need to get As in all courses.

Comment: _He deserves full marks for his hardworking and attention_ — No, he doesn't.  Grades (are supposed to) measure mastery, not effort.

Comment: @user3209815 if you understand the content without memorizing the words written, that doesn't mean you lose knowledge..

Comment: @Alexandros any suggestions on how to study enough in the weekends only? which is only 2 days and you wanna divide them for 5 course-load! What he does in weekends actually is focusing on the important knowledge he should gain from each course.

Comment: A working day has 8 hours. He still has 4+ hours to study each day.

Comment: Weekends only? Bah!  During my grad school days, I worked a day job for eight hours, then studied and did school work for another 6-8 hours, getting home around midnight.  Your friend should put on his big-boy pants and get to work.

Comment: Re: on-hold votes, this can perfectly happen in graduate school as well, even more so when grad students pay less attention to coursework and more to research/jobs.

Comment: @BobBrown & Alexandros During week days, he exactly has 9 hours for both studying and sleeping, if we want to forget about something called "mind resting". I am only trying to get help from you guys -not arguing-

Comment: _he needs a IT Bachelor degree for his job_ — If the classes your friend is taking are as useless as you seem to think they are, he should look for a better degree program.  But by taking the class, he's agreed to be graded according to the instructor's standards.  Moreover, by requiring an IT degree, your friend's employer has accepted that social contract and is expecting your friend to do the same.  If news of his cheating got back to his employer, I expect he'd lose his job pretty quickly.

Comment: _I am only trying to get help from you guys -not arguing_ — It may not be your intention, but your responses are pretty much the definition of arguing.

Comment: @JeffE you got it, mate! It is not about the curriculum but about the type of questions. when a book explains about how to connect two computers together, you aren't expected to define "network" nor to memorize words but to be able to connect them in the real world. That's the point. and sorry for taking your time:)

Comment: If he cheats on the small stuff now, and can rationalize it to himself as "it's not important", then your "friend" has a serious character flaw and I wouldn't want him as part of my team. Learning information for exams shouldn't be a memorization game. If you know the material and really learn it you don't need to memorize. Theoretical is important for future debugging. You need to understand the why not just the how or you are setting yourself for 3am conference calls because your system failed.

Comment: @Jad I know this guy - great guy. He builds cars. Great cars. Unfortunately, they do not contain a gear. You see, he has no time to build the cogs, too much detailed effort, and why would you really need them? There's an engine and a chassis. He's very hardworking, so why waste time cutting little cog teeth? Well, and there's this car. Great stuff. Except: either it doesn't run, or, when he turns on the engine, it went full speed into the wall. But really, he's a great car engineer. - Obviously, I invented the example, but that's what your friend is doing.

Comment: He is doing the external requirements, while missing some of the essence. The car in my example is not just flawed - it looks like a car, has many aspects of it, seats, engine, but is ultimately unusable. So will be the degree of your friend if he cuts out an essential aspect of the study. Why study at all? He will be found out quickly, like with my car example.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

He should stop. YMMV with regards to confessions...

He's both harming himself and the reputation of his university. Future employers will look at his qualifications and expect him to know certain things. If he has no idea, then that's not good for anybody.

Being in the unenviable position of having to work full time in order to pay for your studies is no excuse to cheat.

Comment: That's the point.. No one will ask him define system administration at work! So, his cheating won't affect him professionally, he says

Comment: If he's hired as a system administrator, his employer will expect him to know the scope of his duties, in other words, to know the definition of system administration.

Your friend is rationalizing his cheating, *i.e.* lying to himself.

Comment: @BobBrown at that time, he can prepare for his interview. Don't tell me you're still memorizing theory from college days!

Comment: @Jad the fact that most people quickly forget how to answer a precise question word-for-word neither excuses cheating, nor means that the knowledge they had is 100% gone. It comes back easily enough. Cheating is wrong – you cannot rationalize your way out of it.

Comment: _Don't tell me you're still memorizing theory from college days!_ — "Theory" isn't something one _can_ memorize.  But yes, I'd be in pretty serious trouble if I couldn't give definitions for the basic vocabulary of my field.

Comment: @JeffE But you construct those definitions based on a thorough understanding of the concept in question, not on memorising a string of words, which appears to be what is expected of Jads friend.

Comment: @Jad Stop asking us what we people do and the stuff we have memorized. Contrary to your friend, almost all of us have BSc, MSc and even PhD degrees. Your friend has not. So, if he wants to get a BSc degree and we tell him to stop cheating he should stop. Period. Otherwise, why is he asking for advise, if he does not want to listen?

Comment: @Jad *cheat: to act dishonestly or unfairly in order to gain an advantage.* I honestly don't know what else there is to add. It's not our burden to persuade your friend. We have quite unanimously told you that it's wrong, so unless you intend to steer the discussion in a productive direction I suggest we leave it at that.